Show plots at maps
Maybe there is an easy solution for this, but I couldn't find any.
I'm trying to show all of these scatter plots in the following picture at a map, so that I can see more easily trends depending of their location. Right now the plots are simply arranged by their location name. The picture is an example and just a subset of a much bigger dataset (there are a lot more scatter plots).

It would be nice if there is any r-package/solution to generate static maps or if it would be possible to use these single plots on an interactive map in QGIS. Maybe there is a QGIS plugin which I'm not aware of? I'm also happy about other open source suggestions!

In QGIS use Layout Manager, create layout, draw a map and use Add Picture -> Raster Image, point out to your drawing/charts. In R use tmap, or ggplot, or basic plot() functions (together with {sf} and/or {terra} packages).

See this for a solution in QGIS 3.8.0

Thanks to the comment from @grzegorz-sapijaszko I found a suitable hybrid solution (r + qgis) for me. Here is my solution for it:

The plots get generated with a r-script and finally saved as a svg-file with the name of the point in the QGIS-project.

Then the files need to get copied into the QGIS-project-directory. For me it is best in a subfolder.

Next the symbology of the point layer is set to the category "SVG Marker".

In the data defined property for the path of the SVG-Marker the path is put together like this on linux:
'Scatterplots/' || "Name of Point" || '.svg'



Scatterplots is the name of the subdirectory.


Finally adjust the size of the plot to your needs.

Due to the fact that the data for the plots comes from the QGIS-project, it would be nice to keep everything in QGIS. I want to say that generation of the plots in r is working, but it would be nice without a detour. Every suggestion is therefore welcome!
Anyway, the best about this solution is, that thanks to the modern possibilities with QField / Mergin, I can now record data and analyze it as well in the field. Even if the plots can only be updated on the computer so far..

Glad it works. In QGIS's Processing Toolbox you can activate/setup an R scripting and run your scripts from QGIS gui, especially if the scatter plots are based on your map layer. It's covered in doc, however if your script requires fancy packages, I would suggest to set up the QGIS processing paths to your local R library and bin. A few examples of scripts to work with lidar data and/or to calculate UAV path: https://github.com/gsapijaszko/qgis_r_processing if you need to check the syntax.
